# What is the difference between a css boilerplate and framework?

Tags: css, frameworks, boilerplate

I've been researching some css frameworks to use for my shopify theme, and I keep seeing css boilerplates put into the same category as frameworks.

What is the difference between the two?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no difference, it's just two names for the same thing. Boilerplate (in this case) is just a geeky word for a (specific) web layout framework. It could as well be named something else, if the one that coined it felt a bit differently about boilers that day. My guess is it comes from `Boilerplate prototype` (*'a broadly working prototype that is constructed from cheaper or simpler materials'*, according to Wikipedia). It later found meaning in the IT industry in a form of a [Boilerplate code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boilerplate_code). In essence, they're both *'fancy'* words for a `template`, so us geeks can feel better about ourselves.

Comment: That is good to hear. I was so confused because I saw no difference whatsoever. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Not sure if I agree with the above answer.

I agree that "template" and "boilerplate" are different names for the same thing. But frameworks?!

I keep using analogies to help me think. And if I think about the working environment of Monty Python's Terry Gilliam (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xs7WaL44_Iw), I must come to the conclusion that there are in fact differences.

Template/boilerplate: desk with ruler, margins, etc.
Library: cuttings.
Framework: template + library + lights + shooting camera + tape + glass + ....

So, by framework is meant basically ALL the working environment, where we can find templates, libraries, others tools like debuggers, tools for auto-complete, compilers, etc etc.

Does this make any sense?